# Употребление "в данной связи"

Tags: этимология

Употребляется ли в деловой речи выражение "в данной связи"

Comment: в данной связИ - какая-то кривая фраза, лучше употребить "в связИ с этим/с чем" или "поэтому". А вот " в данной свЯзи прослеживается закономерность" - норм.